# Error : Writing in a non-empty collection

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, databricks, azure-databricks

I have been facing issue while writing json to my Cosmos DB. I could able to read data and having an issue while writing the same

An applied following version of Cosmos db connectors 
https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/cosmosdb-connector.html
and tried different versions too. The issue remains to persist.

```
RawFilePath="/mnt/ADLS/Users/test/CosmosDB/testfile.json"
DFRead=spark.read.json(RawFilePath)
DFNew = DFRead.selectExpr("activity", "partition AS xfactor","response", "source", "type")

writeConfig  = {
 "Endpoint" : "{End Point}",
 "Masterkey" : "{MasterKey}",
 "Database" : "{DB Name}",
 "Collection" : "{Connection name}",
 "Upsert" : "true"   
}

DFNew.write.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").options(**writeConfig).save()
```

Getting the following error.

```
Error : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Writing in a non-empty collection.
```

Expecting to write json into cosmos DB collection. But, could not able to resolve non-empty collection error in Databricks. Its really appreciate your help.

thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Try by specifying mode

```
DFNew.write.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").mode("append").options(**writeConfig).save()
```